# how to synch CiviCRM user groups to Joomla ACL groups

Tags: joomla, groups, smartgroups

trying to figure out how to synch CiviCRM groups (especially smart groups!) with Joomla ACL groups.  I did find [this extension](https://github.com/lcdservices/CiviCRM-Group-Sync) (CiviCRM-Group-Sync) but it's 3 years old and last tested systems were Joomla 3.8 and CiviCRM 5.3.2 (some basic testing on my part threw PHP errors).

Is there another extension I'm missing that can do this? If not, and it has to be a custom plugin, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this do what you need: https://github.com/lcdservices/CiviCRM-CiviAuthenticate

Comment: If I understand its functions correctly, no.  It assigns users to ACL groups based on Membership type and/or Membership status.   That's helpful, but I also have a CiviCRM custom field whose value determines whether the person goes into the group or not.  I'm also not sure if this fires only when authentication occurs, or would it also be triggered by a user changing their own value in the custom field?